# Managing Memory for showing large bitmaps in android

Tags: android, memory-management

I know this question is asked several times, but still clarity to my situation would be helpful.

I am showing some images in 2 column grid view. When user taps on an image, I am displaying the image in ViewPager. The Image which is displayed in gridview is about 200X200px and I want to show the same image with enlarged size say about 800X800px in ViewPager in a DialogFragment.

The Actual size of images are huge with different resolutions. I have followed the link http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html and I have scaled down images to size which is required for my app. In ViewPager fragment dialog I am also recycling the image with `bitmap.recycle()` and calling `System.gc()` explicitly(I know this is a bad practice) at PagerFragment onDestroy. But even then I am getting Out of memory error. On top of it, I am encountering this issue only in Android 4.2.1 (Nexus 7) but not on Android 4.1.2( Samsung Tab) and Android 4.4(Nexus 7).

For later 2 android versions, I do not have to call even `System.gc()`. It works very well without this. I have checked Viewpager with some 300 - 400 images. But for former after scrolling 60 images, App is crashing with OutOfmemory error. To resolve this I have used a workaround for now `android:largeHeap="true"` which I think is very bad for myapp and could not digest it.

I really appreciate if anyone who can help me avoid `android:largeHeap="true"`.

In my app, I have to show around 6000 images in GridView and also an enlarged image in ViewPager linked to GridView. I am loading only 20 images from FileSystem asynchronously while scrolling gridview.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Use an LRUCache to hold the images.  Make that the only thing that holds a Bitmap that's not currently on screen.  That way the older bitmaps will be kicked out and garbage collected quickly.